# deleting semicolons in a column of csv in python

Tags: python-2.7, date, datetime

I have a column of different times and I want to find the values in between 2 different times but can't find out how? For example: 09:04:00 threw 09:25:00. And just use the values in between those different times.

I was gonna just delete the semicolons separating hours:minutes:seconds and do it that way. But really don't know how to do that. But I know how to find a value in a column so I figured that way would be easier idk.

Here is the csv I'm working with.

DATE,TIME,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,VOLUME
02/03/1997,09:04:00,3046.00,3048.50,3046.00,3047.50,505
02/03/1997,09:05:00,3047.00,3048.00,3046.00,3047.00,162
02/03/1997,09:06:00,3047.50,3048.00,3047.00,3047.50,98
02/03/1997,09:07:00,3047.50,3047.50,3047.00,3047.50,228
02/03/1997,09:08:00,3048.00,3048.00,3047.50,3048.00,136
02/03/1997,09:09:00,3048.00,3048.00,3046.50,3046.50,174
02/03/1997,09:10:00,3046.50,3046.50,3045.00,3045.00,134
02/03/1997,09:11:00,3045.50,3046.00,3044.00,3045.00,43
02/03/1997,09:12:00,3045.00,3045.50,3045.00,3045.00,214
02/03/1997,09:13:00,3045.50,3045.50,3045.50,3045.50,8
02/03/1997,09:14:00,3045.50,3046.00,3044.50,3044.50,152
02/03/1997,09:15:00,3044.00,3044.00,3042.50,3042.50,126
02/03/1997,09:16:00,3043.50,3043.50,3043.00,3043.00,128
02/03/1997,09:17:00,3042.50,3043.50,3042.50,3043.50,23
02/03/1997,09:18:00,3043.50,3044.50,3043.00,3044.00,51
02/03/1997,09:19:00,3044.50,3044.50,3043.00,3043.00,18
02/03/1997,09:20:00,3043.00,3045.00,3043.00,3045.00,23
02/03/1997,09:21:00,3045.00,3045.00,3044.50,3045.00,51
02/03/1997,09:22:00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,47
02/03/1997,09:23:00,3045.50,3046.00,3045.00,3045.00,77
02/03/1997,09:24:00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,131
02/03/1997,09:25:00,3044.50,3044.50,3043.50,3043.50,138
02/03/1997,09:26:00,3043.50,3043.50,3043.50,3043.50,6
02/03/1997,09:27:00,3043.50,3043.50,3043.00,3043.00,56
02/03/1997,09:28:00,3043.00,3044.00,3043.00,3044.00,32
02/03/1997,09:29:00,3044.50,3044.50,3044.50,3044.50,63
02/03/1997,09:30:00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,28
02/03/1997,09:31:00,3045.00,3045.50,3045.00,3045.50,75
02/03/1997,09:32:00,3045.50,3045.50,3044.00,3044.00,54
02/03/1997,09:33:00,3043.50,3044.50,3043.50,3044.00,96
02/03/1997,09:34:00,3044.00,3044.50,3044.00,3044.50,27
02/03/1997,09:35:00,3044.50,3044.50,3043.50,3044.50,44
02/03/1997,09:36:00,3044.00,3044.00,3043.00,3043.00,61
02/03/1997,09:37:00,3043.50,3043.50,3043.50,3043.50,18

Thanks for the time

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself thoroughly I'm trying to get all of the data in the data frame (DATE,TIME,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,VOLUME ) that are In between this time 09:04:00 and 09:25:00. I should of just said it like that sorry for the confusion I really appreciate everybody's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to replace semicolons with commas you can use the built in [string replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=string.replace#string.replace) function.

```
line = '02/03/1997,09:24:00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,131'
line = line.replace(':',',') 
print(line)
```

Output

> 02/03/1997,09,04,00,3046.00,3048.50,3046.00,3047.50,505

Then split on commas to separate the data.

```
line.split(',')
```

If you only want the numerical values you could also do the following (using a regular expression):

```
import re
line = '02/03/1997,09:04:00,3046.00,3048.50,3046.00,3047.50,505'
values = [float(x) for x in re.sub(r'[^\w.]+', ',', line).split(',')]
print values
```

Which gives you a list of numerical values that you can process.

> [2.0, 3.0, 1997.0, 9.0, 4.0, 0.0, 3046.0, 3048.5, 3046.0, 3047.5, 505.0]

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself thoroughly I'm trying to get all of the data in the data frame (DATE,TIME,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,VOLUME ) that are In between this time 09:04:00 and 09:25:00. I should of just said it like that sorry for the confusion I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module! :)

```
>>>import csv
>>> with open('myFile.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
...     myCsvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
...     for row in myCsvreader:
...         for item in row:
...             item.spit(':')  # Returns hours without semicolons
```

Once you extracted different time stamps, you can use the `datetime` module, such as:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time

x = time(hour=9, minute=30, second=30)
y = time(hour=9, minute=30, second=42)

diff = datetime.combine(date.today(), y) - datetime.combine(date.today(), x)
print diff.total_seconds()
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself thoroughly I'm trying to get all of the data in the data frame (DATE,TIME,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,VOLUME ) that are In between this time 09:04:00 and 09:25:00. I should of just said it like that sorry for the confusion I really appreciate your time.